# Is it possible to automatically cast to most derived type?

Tags: c++

I write a memory scanning app where a "pattern" is made of arbitrary templated "units". The unit class is also derived from a non templated parent wrapper class (so I can store unit pointers in a vector...).

How can I *display* a templated unit member that is not in the parent class without having to manually downcast ?

I'd like to do something like `auto unitT = most_derived_cast(unitW);`

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Wrapper {
public:
    virtual void* get1() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Wrapper {

    T m_value;

public:
    Derived(T value) : m_value{ value } {}

    void* get1() const override {
        return new T(m_value);
    }

    T get2() const {
        return m_value;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<shared_ptr<Wrapper>> wrapped;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        wrapped.emplace_back(new Derived<int>(i));
        wrapped.emplace_back(new Derived<float>(i));
    }

    for (const shared_ptr<Wrapper>& w : wrapped) {

        cout << *w->get1() << " ";                      // bummer; can't dereference from void*

        auto v = w->get2();                             // bummer; w is of type Wrapper

        if (dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived<int>>(w)) {    // bummer; have to manually cast
            cout << *(int*)w->get1() << " ";
            cout << dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived<int>>(w)->get2() << " ";
        }
        else if (dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived<float>>(w)) {
            cout << *(float*)w->get1() << " ";
            cout << dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived<float>>(w)->get2() << " ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "bummer "; // bummer; forgot to implement this...
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible. What you probably need is a virtual function.

Comment: See my example code - there is a virtual function there but the problem stays the same. `get1()` is virtual but can't return a templated type obviously.

Comment: Visitor pattern might be what you are looking for.

Comment: If you cannot name, at the time you write your code, the type you want, the language won't help you. Why do you need your virtual function to return a templated type, whatever it is? You are *printing* stuff. Your virtual function needs to *print*, not return anything.

Comment: "printing" was just an illustrative example. What I really need to do is "store" the return value of `get()` which is of type `T` from a `Wrapper` pointer. Does that make more sense? What I try to avoid is checking all possible derived types of `Wrapper*` manually with `dynamic_pointer_cast`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Store where? how? If storing in your environment is like printing, then there's no difference. If not, your example fails to be illustrative.

Comment: Wow chill out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ Is it possible to automatically cast to most derived type?

No. It is not possible. Usually, when one thinks they need this, what they need is a virtual function.

> How can I display a templated unit member that is not in the parent class without having to manually downcast ?

An example solution:

Add a new virtual function for inserting into a stream:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    virtual std::ostream&
    stream_insert(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
// ...
};
```

Make `Wrapper` streamable, and delegate to the virtual function:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Wrapper& w) { 
    return w.stream_insert(os);
}
```

Implement the function in the derived class:

```
std::ostream&
stream_insert(std::ostream& os) const override {
    return os << m_value;
}
```

You can now insert `Wrapper` instances into character streams:

```
for (const shared_ptr<Wrapper>& w : wrapped) {
        std::cout << *w;
}
```

Comment: My problem is not solved but I guess my question wasn't accurate enough. ostream can accept arbitrary type that is why. I will still mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to automatically cast to most derived type?

As mentioned by eeonika's answer, no it is not.

In general terms, given only a declaration of (or even a definition of) `Wrapper`, the implementation has no information about what classes are derived from it.    The separate compilation model (which allows source files to be compiled independently and linked together) means the compiler has no visibility of derived classes defined in different compilation units.

However, your subject line here is actually the wrong question.   In fact, you have provided a demonstration of the ["XY problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), in which you are trying to do "X", think that "Y" would be a solution, so you have asked how to do "Y" - which in your case, is a problem with no solution, which prevents people from helping you.

In future, when asking questions, try to describe your REAL problem properly ("X") and preferably leave out the description of the solution you have in mind ("Y").

Fortunately, you are in the minority of people who ask how to solve an "XY problem" and have actually bothered to include a description of your REAL problem in the body of your question.   Which means it is possible to help, which I'll attempt now.

> How can I display a templated unit member that is not in the parent class without having to manually downcast ?

The actual solution, again as eeroniko mentioned, is to provide a suitable virtual function.

In your case, the actual problem is that your `Wrapper` class

> ```
> class Wrapper {
> public:
>    virtual void* get1() const = 0;
> };
> ```

has provided a virtual function but, when the function is used in `main()`, that function does not provide enough information for the usage to work

> ```
> cout << *w->get1() << " ";                      // bummer; can't dereference from void*
> ```

To fix this, there are a few steps needed.

**First step** change `Wrapper` so the virtual function does not return `void *`.

```
virtual Wrapper* get1() const = 0;
```

**Second step** Declare an `operator<<()` that allows a `Wrapper` to be output to a stream without changing that object.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Wrapper &);
```

Optionally this function can be declared a friend of `Wrapper`.   The `const` represents a normal expectation that outputting an object to a stream does not change it.    Passing both arguments by reference (the `&` on each argument) is important.

**Third step** Provide another virtual function of `Wrapper` that can be used to do output;

```
virtual void Output(std::ostream &) const;
```

**Fourth step** In your template class `Derived`, override both `virtual` functions.

```
template<typename T> class Derived : public Wrapper
{
     T m_value;

     public:
        Derived(T value) : m_value{ value } {}

        Wrapper * get1() const override
        {
            return this;    //  note that this does not create a clone
        };

        virtual void Output(std::ostream &s) const override
        {
            s << m_value;
        };           

};
```

Note that I have changed `get1()` so it returns the address of the current object.  Your implementation dynamically created a clone, which causes a memory leak (unless the caller takes specific steps to release the dynamically allocated object).

**Fifth Step**  Define the previously declared `operator<<()` so it calls the virtual function

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, const Wrapper &w)
{
     w.Output(s);
     return s;
}
```

The `w.Output(s)` is actually a call of a virtual function.  So if `w` is a reference to a `Derived<int>`, `w.Output(s)` will correctly call `Derived<int>::Output()` without any need to somehow cast a `Wrapper` to `Derived<int>`.

Putting all that together, you will find that the statement

```
 cout << *w->get1() << " ";
```

now works.   The mechanics is that `get1()` returns the address of the object (i.e. it returns `w`).   The `*` obtains a reference to the pointed-to object.   Then `operator<<()` calls the virtual function, and that resolves (since `w` points at a `Derived<int>` or a `Derived<float>`) to the correct overload of `Output()` - which, since it is a member of the templated class `Derived`, correctly accesses the member `m_value`.

**Additional niceties you may wish to consider**

**1)** Although I have omitted your `get2()` member of the templated `Derived<T>` if needed, that function could also be called by `Derived<T>::Output()`(but not by the `operator<<()` since `Wrapper` has no such function, and `operator<<()` knows nothing about what classes are derived from `Wrapper`).

**2)** Although your statement

```
 cout << *w->get1() << " ";
```

will now work, it is possible to omit everything related to `get1()` entirely, and simply do

```
 cout << *w << " ";
```

to output the object correctly, since `*w` obtains a reference (of type `Wrapper &`) to the object pointed to by `w`.   Which means `operator<<()` will correctly call the most derived form of the virtual function `Output()`.

**Final note**  I reemphasise that there is no need to solve the impossible question you asked (how to automatically cast to the most derived type).

Comment: I think saying I want to "display" values is misleading (I used that as an illustrative example) because `ostream<<` can take arbitrary types - what I really want to do is *store* the value returned by `get()`, which is of type `T`, through a `Wrapper*` interface. Is that even possible? Running in circles here :p

Comment: Depends on what you mean when you say you want to "store" the value returned by `get()`, and what you want to do with it once you have stored it.  If you can't be clear on what you want to achieve  it's not possible to design/implement any solution to achieve it  (unleashing fingers on keyboard to hack out some C++ code is unlikely to solve the problem, if you can't CLEARLY describe to yourself what you're trying to achieve before you unleash those fingers).

Comment: I discussed how to do the streaming, since you asked how to display a templated member, and the action in your code that could be said to do anything like "display" was related to outputting something to a stream.   You may want to look at this link   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're right actually - I can't clearly describe to myself what I am trying to achieve. I'll give you a really quick example tho: let's say I want to display m_value in a GUI form of some sort. The form fields must be instanced based on the type they have to display, e.g. an `int` field to display a `Derived<int>::m_value` - but through a `Wrapper*` pointer.

Comment: Wow.   It's a huge leap from a requirement like that to trying to cast from a base class to the most derived class.  It's a bit hard to give definitive advice for that - you've simply left too many things unspecified (e.g. how are the various types of GUI components created and updated, and how are THOSE objects related to each other?) to be sure.  However, I'd guess (and it is only a guess) you're looking for something based on the Model-Vew-Controller architectural pattern.  You really need to spend time on clearly describing what you're trying to achieve, before seeking a solution, though.

Comment: Well my question just boils down to getting the most derived type from a parent class pointer. I know I can achieve this with `dynamic_pointer_cast` checks or storing a [derived instance type] in a string (with `typeid()`) - I just wondered if there is another way than manually checking for all possible derived types. I think this explains it pretty well. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: That's the question you asked, yeah.   And, as explained, it is not possible without doing it "manually"  (checking if it is one of a number of known types).    However, as you've provided more information on what you are ACTUALLY trying to do, the question (or the type of solution you are seeking) is not relevant.   Until you get past your belief that you need to obtain the derived type, you won't move forward to find a solution to your actual problem.

Comment: You don't understand my point. In order to correctly "display" arbitrary data from a `void*` or `char*` I need to know which type to reinterpret to, which is the templated type of `Derived<T>`. That is because I read data from a remote process memory and that data could represent anything. Btw this is the first thing I mentioned in my question - maybe it wasnt clear enough sorry. So to summarize: first I identify patterns in memory with arbitrary pattern units, and then I "read back" matching memory locations according to the templated types of said units. I guess Ill do it manually then.